# Firebase localised tags data structure that allow filtering by tags

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want to list all data from /products collection. But I also want to get data from /products collection filtered by tags.

So the case is: get all products that have tags red, greed and blue. Tags are also searchable in app by specific language but ID should be the same that is why I am referencing IDs from products.

My design idea:

```
/tags
  -tag_id_1: {en: "red", de: "rot"}
  -tag_id_2: {en: "green", de: "grün"}
  -tag_id_3: {en: "blue", de: "blau"}

/products
  -PRODUCT_1
    -title: ""
    -description: ""
    -date: ""
    -tags: [tag_id_1,tag_id_2,tag_id_3] 
  -PRODUCT_2
    -title: ""
    -description: ""
    -date: ""
    -tags: [tag_id_3]
```

Now to the problem:

- Should I duplicate selected tags translations in each product and have `tagIds:[]` and `tags: {{tag},{tag}...}`
- With this structure is it possible to fetch all products that has `tag_id_1,tag_id_2,tag_id_3` ordered by `date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tags in your schema contain colors in different languages, a possible database schema that can help you query all products by specific colors might look like this:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- products (collection)
         |
         --- $productId (document)
                |
                --- title: "T-shirt"
                |
                --- description: "It's awesome."
                |
                --- date: "2022-07-22"
                |
                --- colors (map)
                     |
                     --- en
                     |   |
                     |   --- red: true
                     |   |
                     |   --- green: true
                     |   |
                     |   --- blue: true
                     |
                     --- de
                         |
                         --- rot: true
                         |
                         --- grün: true
                         |
                         --- blau: true
```

A user can only have a single language set on the device. That being said, if the device is set for example, in English, to get all products that can be red, green as well as blue, the following query is required:

```
db.collection("products")
        .whereEqualTo("colors.en.red", true)
        .whereEqualTo("colors.en.green", true)
        .whereEqualTo("colors.en.blue", true);
```

Remember that this kind of query is an AND and **not** an OR.

Comment: Hey, 1110. Have you tried the solution in my answer? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: In the end I implemented like I posted in question. And use array-contains-any since I need all products that contain any tag that user select in filter.